# MySQL Update Database Command not Working

Tags: mysql

I now have a MySQL Command for Updating a Row of a MySQL Table with Values from another Table.

```
 update info set info.artist = playlist.artist 
 from playlist 
 where info.songname = playlist.songname
```

There is an Syntax Error. But I can see anything in there.

[1st Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kmnM.png)

[2nd Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvA4f.png)

Thanks :)

Comment: See `UPDATE ` syntax, this is not how you can update a table. Hint: you can use `FROM` only with `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 UPDATE info
 INNER JOIN playlist ON info.songname = playlist.songname 
 SET info.artist = playlist.artist
```

2nd Sample:

```
 UPDATE info
 INNER JOIN (
   SELECT songname, artist
   FROM playlist
   WHERE playlist.time_requested IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY playlist.time_requested
   LIMIT 1
 ) PL ON info.songname = PL.songname
 SET info.artist = PL.artist
```

Comment: This is working, but how can I combine it with "WHERE time_requested IS NOT NULL order by time_requested asc LIMIT 1"? Thanks

Comment: which table has time_requested column?

Comment: Why it's PL and not playlist?

Comment: playlist is the entire playlist table, without WHERE and LIMIT conditions, PL is a temporary alias, of the playlist, with the WHERE and LIMIT conditions.  In other words, PL is the alias of the entire (SELECT...) sub-query